# Как скомпилировать в один большой исполняемый файл?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake

Компилирую под линукс исполняемый файл. Он зависит от большого количества so-библиотек. Можно ли их все скомпилировать в один большой исполняемый файл?

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев Вам хватит такой строки в CMakeLists.txt файле

```
set_target_properties(your_target_name PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-static" )
```

Но только будьте готовы к тому, что для многих либ придется искать их статические версии. А это может быть не тривиальным занятием.

Больше почитать о других способах на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648357/compiling-a-static-executable-with-cmake).

Comment: Практически все основные библиотеки имеют в составе linux-дистрибутивов статические версии. Их просто нужно доустановить. Ну а если не имеют, то никто не мешает собрать их самостоятельно из исходников, которые опять же присутствуют в дистрибутивах.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала посмотрите сколько динамических библиотек загружается в исполняемом файле.

```
> ldd filename
```

Дальше опцию компиляции при компоновке исполняемого файла

```
> g++ -static-libstdc++ ...
```

Посмотрите разницу...
Размер файла будет очень большим, а библиотек не уменьшится.

Comment: стрипнуть можно лишний вес

Comment: указанный ключик не подключает **все** библиотеки статически, а лишь одну, которая хранит рантайм с++.